# Bold Specific Elements from JSON Array in Rich Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, string-formatting

I'm currently facing an issue with the formatting of a chunk of text which is retrieved from a webserver as a JSON array.

What I am trying to acomplish is to format the text in a way that can be easily read by the user. An Example output of what I am trying to achieve is:

**This is a Title**

This is a little informative paragraph based on the subject selected

**This is a secondary title**

This is another paragraph

The way the string looks (before modification):

> {"Title":"This is a Title", "Content_One": "This is alittle
>   informative paragraph based on the subject selected", "Title_Two":
>   "This is another paragraph"}

My current application is using Winforms, and I'm attempting to pump this into a Rich Text Box (hopefully going to handle the correct formatting). As a little long shot, I tried returning HTML Tags (Very long shot) For this to provide no change to the text.

I have also tried individually iterating through the array, and attempting to pramatically bold out certain elements from the JSON Array. None of which I have tried have provided expected output.

Attempt one:

```
 TTKNormalContent.Text = new Font(ReturnArr.Title, FontStyle.Bold).ToString();
```

Which returns:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll

---

Attempt one:

```
TTKNormalContent.Text = ReturnArr.Title;
TTKNormalContent.SelectionFont = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Which does not bold out the text

---

Attempt Two:

I can temporarily make the text bold by:

```
  TTKNormalContent.Font = new Font(TTKNormalContent.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
  TTKNormalContent.Text = ReturnArr.Title;
```

But adding:

```
TTKNormalContent.Font = new Font(TTKNormalContent.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
TTKNormalContent.Text += ReturnArr.ContentOne;
```

Which will remove the boldness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AppendText`. When you use `Text+= "something"` you replace the format.

You can use this example:

```
var json = "{\"Title\":\"This is a Title\", \"Content_One\": \"This is alittle informative paragraph based on the subject selected\", \"Title_Two\": \"This is another paragraph\"}";
var start = 0;
Dictionary<string, string> values = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

values.Cast<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(item.Key);
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText( ":" );
            start += item.Key.Length + 1;
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(item.Value);
            this.richTextBox1.Select(start, item.Value.Length);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(this.richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText("\n");
            start += item.Value.Length + 1;
        });
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: To use sample, don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` and also if you need to use `JavaScriptSerializer`, add reference `System.Web.Extensions` and add `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

Comment: Have had to make slight modifications to the provided code, as i'm currently building the application around JSON.net. But this works exactly as needed. Thank you